# Calculating the Electrostatic Energy of a Charged Sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, energy, electric-fields, gauss-law

I'm trying to solve this problem :

> Given a distribution of volumetric charge density in space:
> where $r$, is the distance from the beginning of the axes: $$\rho(r)=\left\{
> \begin{array}{cc}
> \frac{A}{r} & r<R \\
> 0 & r\geq R
> \end{array}
> \right.$$ In addition, there exists on the surface charge density $\sigma$
> on the surface $r=R$. It is also given that the field at the point $r=2R$ is defined by
> $$
> \vec{E}(2 R)=\frac{A}{\varepsilon_0} \hat{r} $$

> 1. Calculate the electric field vector in the region r < R.
> 2. Calculate the surface charge density on the spherical surface r = R .
> 3. Calculate the electric field vector in the region r > R.
> 4. Calculate $\phi(r)$, the electric potential function in space
> 5. What is the electrostatic energy of the charged system?

**I only need help with 5** , so I'll give the answers of 1-5 from my professor and I'll jump to 5 .

> Answers :
> $\begin{align}
>     & 1.\quad \vec{E}=\frac{4 R^2 A}{\varepsilon_0 r^2} \hat{r} \quad, \quad
>     2.\quad \sigma=3.5 A \quad, \quad
>     3.\quad \vec{E}=2 \pi k A \hat{r} \quad, \\
>     & 4.\quad \varphi=\left\{
>     \begin{array}{ll}
>     2 \pi k A(9 R-r) & r<R \\
>     \frac{16 \pi k A R^2}{r} & r \geq R
>     \end{array}\right\} \quad, \quad
>     5.\quad U=\frac{386 \pi^2 k A^2 R^3}{3} \quad
> \end{align}
> $

My issue with 5 is the **Surface Area Integral** , My solution yields :

For $r<R$ :
$$U=\frac{1}{2}\left(\iiint \varphi \rho d V+\iint \varphi \sigma d a\right)$$
$$\begin{aligned} & U_1=\frac{1}{2}\left(\iiint 2 \pi k A(9 R-r) \cdot \frac{A}{r} d r+\iint 2 \pi k A(9 R-r) \cdot 3.5 \ A d a\right) \\ & U_1=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int 2 \pi k A(9 R-r) \cdot \frac{A}{1} \cdot 4 \pi r d r+2 \pi k A(9 R-r) \cdot {3.5 A} \cdot 2 \pi r d r\right)= \\ & U_1=\frac{1}{2}\left(72 \pi ^2 k A^2 R \int_0^R r d r-8 \pi^2 k A^2 \int_0^R r^2 d r\right)+14 \pi^2 k A^2 \cdot\left[9 R \int_0^R r d r \cdot \int_0^R r^2 dr \right] \\ & U_1=18 r^2 k A^2 R^3-4 \pi^2 k A^2 \frac{R^3}{3}+126 r^2 k A R^3+14 \pi^2 k A^2\left(R^3 \cdot\left(\frac{9}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right)\right) \\ & U_1=\frac{428}{3} \pi^2 k A^2 R^3+\frac{175}{3} \pi^2 k A^2 R^3\end{aligned}$$

For $r>R$ :
$$U_2=\frac{1}{2}\left(\iiint \varphi \cdot 0 d V\right) =  0$$

Finally :
$$U_{tot} = U_1 + U_2 \neq U_{Official}$$

My other try :

Since
$dq = \sigma \cdot da$

in $(2)$ I got that $Q_\text{Enc on Surface} = 14 \pi R^2 A$

thus :
$$U_{surface}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\iint \varphi \sigma d a\right) = 7 \pi R^2 A \cdot 16\pi k A R = 112\pi^2kA^2R^2$$

Which as well.. yields :

$$U_{tot} = U_1 + U_2 \neq U_{Official}$$

**I Would like to know what I'm doing wrong or some direction to the correct answer ..**